# Upate Multiple SelectInput with data from reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am facing a hard time with this shiny app and I was hoping I could get some help here. The data is mtcars I just added a column to represent a fictional amount of money. The flow is basically this:

1.- The user selects a variable they want to group_by ('cyl','vs','am','gear','carb'), then a table will show on screen with the data already grouped by the variable that the user selected, the user can group by multiple variables.

2.- After that if they selected to group_by let's say 'am' and 'gear' two selectInput's with the information of those variables will show on screen to create another table with filtered data depending on the selectInput's. The data is filtered in order, so if in 'am' the value is "0" the 'gear' selectInput will only show you "3" and "4" because there are the only choices available for 'gear' if you choose "0" in 'am' and the result is shown in another table below the grouped table.

Everything works fine, the selectInput's only show the variables according to the selected values and the filter also works, but when I try to select another option in the selectInput's that filter the data, it only shows briefly the result and then it goes back to the value set by default so I can not see the data for other options.

I have done my research and I assume that it has something to do with an event that is triggering twice and resets the value instantly, but I've been trying a lot of stuff and I can't get it to work.

[The output looks something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8h8n.png)

And here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data(mtcars)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput('group_filter'),
                 uiOutput('cb_cyl'),
                 uiOutput('cb_vs'),
                 uiOutput('cb_am'),
                 uiOutput('cb_gear'),
                 uiOutput('cb_carb')),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('grouped_table'),
      dataTableOutput('filtered_table')
    ),
    
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data<-mtcars
  data$Amount_Money<-0
  
  for (i in 1:length(data$mpg)) {
    data[i,12]<-sample(50000:100000,1)
  }
  categories<-c('cyl','vs','am','gear','carb')
  
  output$group_filter <- renderUI({
    
    pickerInput("grouper", "Group by: ", 
                choices = levels(as.factor(categories)),
                multiple = TRUE
    )})
  
  grouped_data<- 
    reactive ({
      req(input$grouper)
      data %>% group_by_at(input$grouper) %>% summarise(Money=sum(Amount_Money))
      
    })
  
  output$grouped_table<-renderDataTable(grouped_data())
  
  filtered_data<-reactive({
    
    req(input$grouper)
    data<-grouped_data()
    if (is.null(input$filter_cyl)) id_cyl <- "ALL" else id_cyl<-input$filter_cyl
    if (is.null(input$filter_vs)) id_vs <- "ALL" else id_vs<-input$filter_vs
    if (is.null(input$filter_am)) id_am <- "ALL" else id_am<-input$filter_am
    if (is.null(input$filter_gear)) id_gear <- "ALL" else id_gear<-input$filter_gear
    if (is.null(input$filter_carb)) id_carb <- "ALL" else id_carb<-input$filter_carb
    
    available_filters<<-colnames(data)
    number_filters<<-length(available_filters)-1 #NOT COUNTING AMOUNT MONEY COLUMN
    
    for (i in 1:number_filters) { #THESE FOR GUARANTEES THAT THE DATA IS FILTER IN THE ORDER THAT THE USER SPECIFIED
      
      if (available_filters[i]=="cyl") {
        choices_cyl<-unique(data$cyl) #I NEED TO DEFINE CHOICES BEFORE THE FILTER SO THE USER CAN CHANGE TO THE OTHER CYL OPTIONS
        data<-data %>% 
          filter(cyl==id_cyl) #NOW THAT THE DATA IS FILTERED BY THE VALUE THE USER SELECTED THE NEXT FILTERS WILL ONLY THE VALUE SELECTED HERE
      }
      if (available_filters[i]=="vs") {
        choices_vs<-unique(data$vs) 
        data<-data %>% 
          filter(vs==id_vs) 
      }
      if (available_filters[i]=="am") {
        choices_am<-unique(data$am) 
        data<-data %>% 
          filter(am==id_am) 
      }
      if (available_filters[i]=="gear") {
        choices_gear<-unique(data$gear) 
        data<-data %>% 
          filter(gear==id_gear) 
      }
      if (available_filters[i]=="carb") {
        choices_carb<-unique(data$carb) 
        data<-data %>% 
          filter(carb==id_carb) 
      }
      
    }
    result<-list(1)
    if (exists("choices_cyl")) result[[1]]<-choices_cyl
    if (exists("choices_vs")) result[[2]]<-choices_vs
    if (exists("choices_am")) result[[3]]<-choices_am
    if (exists("choices_gear")) result[[4]]<-choices_gear
    if (exists("choices_carb")) result[[5]]<-choices_carb
    result[[6]]<-data
    
    return(result)
    
  })
  
  output$filtered_table<-renderDataTable(filtered_data()[[6]])
  
  output$cb_cyl <- renderUI({
    base<-filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("cyl" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_cyl',
                  label ="cyl: ",
                  choices = sort(filtered_data()[[1]]), #sort(l)
                  selected = sort(filtered_data()[[1]])[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)     
    }
  })
  
  output$cb_vs <- renderUI({
    base<-filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("vs" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_vs',
                  label ="vs: ",
                  choices = sort(filtered_data()[[2]]), #sort(l)
                  selected = sort(filtered_data()[[2]])[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)     
    }
  })
  
  output$cb_am <- renderUI({
    base<-filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("am" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_am',
                  label ="am: ",
                  choices = sort(filtered_data()[[3]]), #sort(l)
                  selected = sort(filtered_data()[[3]])[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)     
    }
  })
  
  output$cb_gear <- renderUI({
    base<-filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("gear" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_gear',
                  label ="gear: ",
                  choices = sort(filtered_data()[[4]]), #sort(l)
                  selected = sort(filtered_data()[[4]])[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)     
    }
  })
  
  output$cb_carb <- renderUI({
    base<-filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("carb" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_carb',
                  label ="carb: ",
                  choices = sort(filtered_data()[[5]]), #sort(l)
                  selected = sort(filtered_data()[[5]])[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)     
    }
  })
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use `local()` in your `for` loop.  Then the second table appears correctly.

Comment: Sorry this is the first time I heard of the `local()` function, so I need to wrap all the for cycle like `local( for {...})`?

Comment: Never mind.  There seems to be more issues.  I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues.  There is no need to use `for` loop.  If you needed it, it is best to use `local` inside it.  You can google on how to use `for` loops inside `shiny` (lazy evaluation, etc.). Also, you are using `filtered_data` inside renderUI for each `selectInput`. However, you are using the input variables from those same `selectInput`s to define the `filtered_data`.  It is best to switch it to `grouped_data` in each `renderUI`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput('group_filter'),
                 uiOutput('cb_cyl'),
                 uiOutput('cb_vs'),
                 uiOutput('cb_am'),
                 uiOutput('cb_gear'),
                 uiOutput('cb_carb')
                 ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput('grouped_table'),
      DTOutput('filtered_table')
    ),
    
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data<-mtcars
  data$Amount_Money<-0
  
  for (i in 1:length(data$mpg)) {
    data[i,12]<-sample(50000:100000,1)
  }
  categories<-c('cyl','vs','am','gear','carb')
  
  output$group_filter <- renderUI({
    
    pickerInput("grouper", "Group by: ", 
                choices = levels(as.factor(categories)),
                multiple = TRUE
    )})
  
  grouped_data <- reactive({
      req(input$grouper)
      data %>% group_by_at(input$grouper) %>% 
        dplyr::summarise(Money=sum(Amount_Money)) %>% ungroup()
    })
  
  output$grouped_table<-renderDT(grouped_data())
  
  filtered_data<-reactive({
    
    req(input$grouper)
    data<-grouped_data()
    if (is.null(input$filter_cyl)) id_cyl <- "ALL" else id_cyl<-input$filter_cyl
    if (is.null(input$filter_vs)) id_vs <- "ALL" else id_vs<-input$filter_vs
    if (is.null(input$filter_am)) id_am <- "ALL" else id_am<-input$filter_am
    if (is.null(input$filter_gear)) id_gear <- "ALL" else id_gear<-input$filter_gear
    if (is.null(input$filter_carb)) id_carb <- "ALL" else id_carb<-input$filter_carb
    
    available_filters <- colnames(data)
    
    number_filters <- length(available_filters) #NOT COUNTING AMOUNT MONEY COLUMN
    
    # for (i in 1:number_filters) { #THESE FOR GUARANTEES THAT THE DATA IS FILTER IN THE ORDER THAT THE USER SPECIFIED
    #   local({
    #     i <- i
        if ("cyl" %in% available_filters) {
          choices_cyl<-unique(data$cyl) #I NEED TO DEFINE CHOICES BEFORE THE FILTER SO THE USER CAN CHANGE TO THE OTHER CYL OPTIONS
          data<-data %>% 
            dplyr::filter(cyl %in% input$filter_cyl) #NOW THAT THE DATA IS FILTERED BY THE VALUE THE USER SELECTED THE NEXT FILTERS WILL ONLY THE VALUE SELECTED HERE
        }
        if ("vs" %in% available_filters) {
          choices_vs<-unique(data$vs) 
          data<-data %>% 
            dplyr::filter(vs %in% input$filter_vs) 
        }
        if ("am" %in% available_filters) {
          choices_am<-unique(data$am) 
          data<-data %>% 
            dplyr::filter(am %in% input$filter_am) 
        }
        if ("gear" %in% available_filters) {
          choices_gear<-unique(data$gear) 
          data<-data %>% 
            dplyr::filter(gear %in% input$filter_gear) 
        }
        if ("carb" %in% available_filters) {
          choices_carb<-unique(data$carb) 
          data<-data %>% 
            dplyr::filter(carb %in% input$filter_carb) 
        }
    #   })
    # }
    
    result<-list(1)
    if (exists("choices_cyl")) result[[1]]<-choices_cyl
    if (exists("choices_vs")) result[[2]]<-choices_vs
    if (exists("choices_am")) result[[3]]<-choices_am
    if (exists("choices_gear")) result[[4]]<-choices_gear
    if (exists("choices_carb")) result[[5]]<-choices_carb
    result[[6]]<-data
    return(result)
    
  })
  
  output$filtered_table<-renderDT(datatable(filtered_data()[[6]]) )
  
  output$cb_cyl <- renderUI({
    base<- grouped_data() # filtered_data()[[6]]
    
    if ("cyl" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_cyl',
                  label ="cyl: ",
                  choices = unique(base$cyl), 
                  selected = base$cyl[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  output$cb_vs <- renderUI({
    base<- grouped_data() #filtered_data()[[6]]
    
    if ("vs" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_vs',
                  label ="vs: ",
                  choices = unique(base$vs),  
                  selected = base$vs[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  output$cb_am <- renderUI({
    base<- grouped_data() # filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("am" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_am',
                  label ="am: ",
                  choices = unique(base$am), #sort(l)
                  selected = base$am[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  output$cb_gear <- renderUI({
    base<- grouped_data() # filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("gear" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_gear',
                  label ="gear: ",
                  choices = unique(base$gear), #sort(l)
                  selected = base$gear[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  output$cb_carb <- renderUI({
    base<- grouped_data() # filtered_data()[[6]]
    if ("carb" %in% colnames(base)) {
      selectInput(inputId = 'filter_carb',
                  label ="carb: ",
                  choices = unique(base$carb), #sort(l)
                  selected = base$carb[1])
    } else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The `for` I use it basically to filter in the order the user select the variables so if he chooses first 'am' and then 'gear' the loop will filter the data set in that order and update the `selectInput`s in response to that. I think there is still an issue, for example if I choose 'am' with value '0' the only options that should be available on the gear `selectInput`are '3' and '4' but in this case there is also number '5'

Comment: In that case, check out [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/selectizeGroup-module.html)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, just finished reading the page you just told me and changing my code using that information and now it works. Thank you!